# How to fix alignment of text not image in div?

Tags: html, alignment

Is it possible to align my text to the vertical middle. I've used `valign`, `text-align` and `padding` but will doesn't work. Also, I don't want any image to align with text.

Solution needs to be HTML only.[image]

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
```

```html
<div style="background:#2f2f2f;height:42px;width:250px;"><i><b style="padding-top:10px;text-align:middle">Text</a></div>
```

Comment: Could you post an image of your expected final result?
That way will be more easy to understand what you need.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS are invalid, please [edit] your question to fix the code and also explain exactly what you are trying to do - you say "vertically middle" *and* "fix to bottom" which are two different alignments.

Comment: You still haven't corrected your HTML - questions here on Stack Overflow are meant to be helpful for *all* users, and a question with invalid HTML is not useful and it is not clear what was causing the problem in the first place. You have edited your question but you still have not fixed your invalid HTML. Please fix this to improve your question so that you might get the answers you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to the div.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
```

```html
<div style="background:#2f2f2f;height:42px;width:250px;display: flex;
align-items: center;"><i><b style="padding-top:10px;text-align:middle">Text</a></div>
```

Also, the html format is not valid, a better code would be something like this:

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
}

   .container {
    background: #2f2f2f;
    height: 42px;
    width: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Yummi Sure, to add horizontal Center just add `justify-content: center;` to the div.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this one. If you want to make the text go to the center you just write this code:

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: thx esteban, that flex function do the trick, but one more thing; can i still center the text?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has some syntax errors, and you need to use negative margins in this case to align to the bottom center.

```css
body {
  background-color: #6B6B6B;
}

.bottomcenter {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:25%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:#2f2f2f;height:42px; text-align:center;" class="bottomcenter"><i><a style="padding-top:10px;">Text</a></i></div>
```

Comment: how can i upload post a image example? here is the url http://wizzfree.com/pix/example.jpg

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) should help.

Comment: @Yummi My answer seems to answer your question. Does it?

Comment: sorry it does not. see example image.

Comment: @Yummi Then what are you looking for? You wanted text aligned to center + bottom centered.